Confusion in proof of $H^1(X,\mathcal{O})=0$ where $X$ is an open disk
In Otto Forster's Lecture on Riemann Surfaces, I have faced a small confusion in which I am certainly overlooking something in the proof of Theorem 13.4 that for $X:= \{z\in \mathbb{C}: |z|<R\}, 0<R \leq \infty$ we have $H^1(X,\mathcal{O})=0$ where $\mathcal{O}$ is the sheaf of holomorphic functions on $X$.
Background which may be skipped

In chapter 12, he defines the Čech cohomology groups as follows: Suppose $X$ is a topological space and $\mathscr{F}$ is a sheaf of abelian groups on $X$. Suppose that an open covering $\mathfrak{U}=(U_i)_{i\in I}$ of $X$ is given. For $q=0,1,2,\dots$ define the $q$th cochain group of $\mathscr{F}$, with respect to $\mathfrak{U}$, as
$$C^q(\mathfrak{U},\mathscr{F}):=\prod\limits_{(i_0,\dots,i_q)\in I^{q+1}} \mathscr{F}(U_{i_0}\cap\dots\cap U_{i_q})$$
Thus a $q$-cochain is a family $$(f_{i_q\dots i_q})_{i_0,\dots,i_q \in I^{q+1}}\quad  \textrm{such that} \quad f_{i_q\dots i_q} \in \mathscr{F}(U_{i_0}\cap\dots\cap U_{i_q}) $$
for all $(i_0,\dots,i_q)\in I^{q+1}$.
Then we have coboundary operators raising the degree of the cochain and specifically for $0$-chains and $1$-chains:

For $(f_i)_{i\in I} \in C^0(\mathfrak{U},\mathscr{F})$, let $\delta((f_i)_{i\in I}) = (g_{ij})_{i,j\in I}$ where
$$g_{ij}:= f_j|_{U_i \cap U_j} - f_i|_{U_i \cap U_j} \in \mathscr{F}(U_i \cap U_j)$$
For $(f_{ij})_{i,j\in I} \in C^1(\mathfrak{U},\mathscr{F})$, let $\delta((f_{ij})) = (g_{ijk})$ where
$$g_{ijk}:= f_{jk}|_{U_i \cap U_j \cap U_k} - f_{ik}|_{U_i \cap U_j \cap U_k} + f_{ij}|_{U_i \cap U_j \cap U_k} \in \mathscr{F}(U_i \cap U_j \cap U_k)$$

Then $$H^1(\mathfrak{U},\mathscr{F}) = \frac{Z^1(\mathfrak{U},\mathscr{F}):=\ker C^1(\mathfrak{U},\mathscr{F}) \to C^2(\mathfrak{U},\mathscr{F})}{B^1(\mathfrak{U},\mathscr{F}):=\mathrm{Im}\, C^0(\mathfrak{U},\mathscr{F}) \to C^1(\mathfrak{U},\mathscr{F}) }$$
This definition depends on the covering but $H^1(X,\mathscr{F})$ is the inductive limit under the directed system of refinements of open coverings, which considers all coverings.
Issue

Theorem 12.8 (Leray) states that if $\mathfrak{U}$ is an open covering such $H^1(U_i,\mathscr{F})=0$ for all $U_i \in \mathfrak{U}$ then
$$H^1(X,\mathscr{F}) \cong H^1(\mathfrak{U},\mathscr{F})$$
and such a covering is called Leray.
Then, theorem 13.4 shows that for an open disk in $\mathbb{C}$ (possibly of infinite radius)one has $H^1(X,\mathcal{O})=0$. This is proved by cohomological construction and Dolbeault's lemma that provides a differentiable $f$ which solves $$\frac{\partial f}{\partial \bar{z}} = g$$ for differentiable $g$.
However, isn't this result immediate from the definition of cohomology and Leray's theorem? Since these open disks are open covers of themselves, just choose $\mathfrak{U}= X$. Then when considering $Z^1(\mathfrak{U},\mathcal{O})$ we need to choose a $1$-chain $(f_{ij})$ but since there is only one set, there is only one chain to consider $f_{11} \in \mathcal{O}(X \cap X)= \mathcal{O}(X)$ which is just a holomorphic function on the open disk. But then cocycles, elements of $Z^1(\mathfrak{U},\mathcal{O})$ are
$$\begin{align*}&f_{111}=f_{11}-f_{11}+f_{11}=0 \implies f_{11}=0 \\& \implies Z^1(\mathfrak{U},\mathcal{O}) = 0 \implies H^1(\mathfrak{U},\mathcal{O}) =0\end{align*}$$
Then since this is the only set of the open cover, by Leray's theorem
$$H^1(X,\mathcal{O}) \cong H^1(\mathfrak{U},\mathcal{O}) = 0$$
Obviously, if this was the case, it would've been done immediately. I believe I am misunderstanding or overlooking something subtle in these definitions. Clarification would be greatly appreciated!

Your shortened proof is true, but it's circular until you know the cohomology of the disk vanishes. The definition of Cech cohomology says we have to take a direct limit over all the opens; Leray's theorem says it's enough to take opens such that the higher cohomology of all their intersections vanish. It's totally true that disks are such an open, but to prove that they are such an open, you can't appeal to Leray's theorem since you don't know their higher vanishes yet.

Sorry, still a bit confused, haven't I shown $H^1(\mathfrak{U},\mathcal{O})=0$ just by showing the only $1$-cocycles are trivial since there is only one set in the open cover taken to be the space itself?

You don't know without Leray's theorem (+ the result you are trying to prove) that the sets in your open cover are small enough to accurately compute the Cech comology, which, a priori, requires you to take a limit over a bunch of covers. (Otherwise, the same proof would show the cohomology of anything vanishes.)

Firstly, I agree that this proof would show anything vanishes and that's how I came to this realization that my understanding is wrong.
Secondly, I'm still not quite following, even though I've reread what you said. Leray's says that I can compute $H^1$ on the whole space by a single covering as long as $H^1$ vanishes on each set in the cover. I have shown a cover where such behavior happens trivially.
It seems you are saying that $H^1(X,\mathcal{O})$ by definition as a direct limit doesn't match $H^1(X,\mathcal{O})$ when $X$ itself is interpreted as an open cover?

Oh! I think I figured out what you are thinking. Leray's theorem says that if the open sets are small enough in the cover such that their Cech cohomology vanishes (not their cohomology with respect to the particular cover you have chosen, but the direct limit), then this cover suffices to take your Cech cohomology and you don't have to take a limit. In the case of the disk, it is indeed true that its cohomology vanishes and so the trivial cover computes its (trivial) cohomology, but you don't know this till you prove its cohomology vanishes, which is what you are trying to do.

To say the same thing in symbols, the hypothesis of Leray's theorem is that for each $U \in \mathfrak{U}$ (and any intersection of such $U$) we have $H^i(U, \mathcal{F}) = 0$. Note that the $U$ is not fraktur in that formula.

I think I understand what the issue is now. Let $X$ be the topological space defined by an open set $X$, let $\mathfrak{U} = {U_1=X}$ be an open covering defined as $X$ itself. When we want to use Leray's, we need to show $H^1(U_1)=0$ AS a Cech cohomology independent of the covering of $U_1$ itself, not cohomology resulting from that trivial cover of $U_1$, but every cover of $U_1$ which means we need to consider the direct limit. So we are back to square one, trying to compute $H^1(X)$. Leray's requires a good enough cover where all $H^1(U_i)$ vanish as direct limits themselves. Thanks!

Yes, exactly! It was confusing to talk through because once you know the fact about the cohomology of the disk vanishing, then in fact it's absolutely valid to compute the cohomology of $X$ by taking the trivial cover. It's reminiscent of students trying to apply L'Hôpital to compute $\lim_{x \to 0} \sin(x)/x$, unaware that this limit is needed in computing the derivative of the sine function.
